# How do I set elements without a specific class to hidden using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have several divs on a page all with the class "article." I used

```
$(".article:first").addClass("current");
```

to add the class "current" to the first div with class "article." I want all other class="article" divs to be hidden until a button is clicked.

When the page loads, the first class="article" div should be visible. When a button is clicked, the 2nd div should appear, and so on.

Edit: Does it matter that the class="article" divs appear in two differently-classed divs?

```
<div class="roots">
   <div class="article">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="words">
   <div class="article">
   </div>
</div>
```

Would I have to address them differently in JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the initial state of only the first one showing with this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".article").hide();  // hide them all
    $(".article:first").show().addClass("current");  // show first one and add class
});
```

Though, I wouldn't personally use JS for the initial state myself because they elements may show briefly before the JS runs and it might not look so clean.  It might be better to have `.article` be hidden by default with CSS:

```
.article {display: none;}
```

And, then you run this initial javascript to show the first one and add your current class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".article:first").show().addClass("current");  // show first one and add class+
});
```

Then, upon a button press, to show the next one that's hidden you can execute this:

```
$("#showButton").click(function() {
    $(".article:hidden:first").show();
});
```

You can see a working example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RPPYz/.

Comment: Do I need to initially hide them all before making the first one visible? Is that required? Also, to show subsequent divs, would I use  $(".article:next") or something similar?

Comment: If they are all initially visible, then you need to hide all the ones you don't want visible and it's easiest and fastest to hide all, then show the one.  See what I've added to my answer recently for what I think is a better way to do it using a combination of CSS and JS.

Comment: Ah nice. I like what you did in the click function.

Comment: I think I commented on it before you made the additions. The last bit of code indicates the first *hidden* div, yes?

Comment: Yes, `".article:hidden:first"` is the first hidden element with class="article".  I've updated the jsFiddle to show moving the .current class to the newly shown article too.  You should definitely look at the code in the jsFiddle because you can see HTML, JS, CSS and output all in one window - very useful for learning and experimenting.

Comment: Wow, that's actually very helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".article").not(":first").hide()
```

or

```
$(".article").not(".current").hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide all but the first post, try this:

```
$(".article").not(":first").hide();
```

To hide all posts *without* the class current, use this:

```
$(".article").not(".current").hide();
```

To show each article one by one when a button is clicked, use this selector:

```
$(".article.current:hidden").first().show();
```

More about the `:hidden` selector can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).